# Is there is reason why the Ruby Tesseract gem doesn't correctly detect bold text?

Tags: ruby, ocr, tesseract

For some reason, on every (PNG/JPG) file I use, Tesseract doesn't accurately flag which words are bold.  I have high quality, high-res, clean images with clear text.

'Is_bold?' result just seems to be random, ie: not based on the image input.  Is this a known issue?

Is there a way to tweak accuracy?